# Translating web responses in .net core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, internationalization, middleware

I'm trying to find a good tutorial about .net localization for http response. Most of the official documentation, has explanation about .resx files and how to change the language of buttons and labels etc of a web page /view .  however, I wish to translate http response of the  web Api calls to user's current locale settings. The http response in my context are strings like "achieved", "pending", "escalated" etc. I can have the corresponding supported culture translations for these strings somewhere in memory or  file. I would like to translate these strings to corresponding current culture where my service is running.

I understand , my question is generic but would be great if someone can share or point to a good tutorial on how to achieve it. I am bit confused on use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");` and below approach

I am trying to intercept the HttpResponse in inline custom middleware as

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();

    if(context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Ok)
    {
        // is it possible to translate here if yes, how ?.. is it good approach?? or any other framework in built better way exists ??
    }              
});
```

Thanks

Comment: If it is possible, I suggest that you can do localization on the web api. So it can return the corresponding data based on the request culture.For more details, you can refer to this [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-use-localization-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, those web api are not in our control, so the data translation has to happen at our end.